# How do I make sure all JavaScript errors are written to the Chrome Developer Tools Console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Consider the following JavaScript function:

```
function triggerError() {
   var something = undefined;
   // The next line will trigger 'TypeError: Cannot call ... of undefined'
   something.doesNotExist();
}
```

When running `triggerError();` directly the following error is written to the Chrome Developer Tools Console in red, which is expected:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'doesNotExist' of undefined
```

However, when `triggerError();` is being run from an event listener no errors are written to the console (the function call just silently dies at `something.doesNotExist();`) which makes things quite tricky to debug in case of typos, etc.

How do I make sure all errors are written to the Chrome Developer Tools Console, including errors generated in code which is being run from event listeners/callbacks?

One obvious work-around would be to add `try { ... } catch (x) { console.log(x) };` all over the place, but since I don't know beforehand where I'll be adding typos this is not a way forward.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in Chrome. You should report it at http://new.crbug.com

Comment: Hm, I *do* get an error message in Chrome - **live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/zzcYH/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you show your sample, I tried to reproduce it on the following snippet and it works perfectly fine for me:

```
<script>
function triggerError() {
   var something = undefined;
   // The next line will trigger 'TypeError: Cannot call ... of undefined'
   something.doesNotExist();
}
window.addEventListener("click", triggerError, true);
</script>
<body onclick="triggerError()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You could  use a `try catch` :**

```
function triggerError() {
    try{
        var something = undefined;
        // The next line will trigger 'TypeError: Cannot call ... of undefined'
        something.doesNotExist();
   }catch(ex){
        console.error(ex.message);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know where I will add my typos, so that won't be of much help unfortunately. I've now made it clear in the question that I'm looking for a fix that does not involve changing the code.